# Numpy transpose multiplication problem

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue

I tried to find the eigenvalues of a matrix multiplied by its transpose but I couldn't do it using numpy.

```
testmatrix = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
prod = testmatrix * testmatrix.T
print eig(prod)
```

I expected to get the following result for the product:

```
5    11    17    23
11    25    39    53
17    39    61    83
23    53    83   113
```

and eigenvalues:

```
0.0000
0.0000
0.3929
203.6071
```

Instead I got `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape` when multiplying `testmatrix` with its transpose.

This works (the multiplication, not the code) in MatLab but I need to use it in a python application.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might find this [tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) useful since you know MATLAB.

Also, try multiplying `testmatrix` with the `dot()` function, i.e. `numpy.dot(testmatrix,testmatrix.T)`

Apparently [`numpy.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) is used between arrays for matrix multiplication! The `*` operator is for element-wise multiplication (`.*` in MATLAB).

Comment: PEP 465 allows the use of the infix `@` operator: `mat1 @ mat2`

Answer (score 8):

You're using element-wise multiplication - the `*` operator on two Numpy matrices is equivalent to the `.*` operator in Matlab. Use

```
prod = numpy.dot(testmatrix, testmatrix.T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another convenient way of representing this operation is `testmatrix @ testmatrix.T`.

The `@` operator in numpy represents matrix multiplication, and can be seen [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul:%7E:text=used%20as%20a-,shorthand,-for%20np.matmul)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).